# Running bottleneck tests for servers

Tags: java

I'm attempting to detect a bottleneck in our servers, and I'm having a hard time deciding where to start. The symptoms from the machine before it crashes are dropped connections (time outs, this is what happens when a client sees when a response takes too long, possibly indicating that a processor couldn't be allocated by the server side code, and the request couldn't be handled) and out of memory issues. The latter error code is actually given by the JVM in an error log, but I have a hard time believing that both the RAM and the lack of available CPUs are turning out to be the bottlenecks at the same time. (In the days of the previous crashes, it has consistently crashed in the manner described above.) We have our own in house server code, and I wouldn't classify it as analogous to Apache or any other code I've seen. (Sorry if this makes giving advice that much more difficult.)

I'd like to take some time to create a somewhat controlled test locally. I'm running the server, and I'm creating a program that will request different things from the local server. What's a good way to monitor RAM/CPU? I'm currently using Java's VisualVM, but monitors stop responding when I hammer it with some of the tests.

Any ideas out there would be greatly appreciated. Like I mentioned, I'm trying to grab as much useful data, to help me further troubleshoot. In general, when a bottleneck issue like this arises, what are some general strategies to take? The live servers are all running on Windows Server 2008. The version of Java is 7.03. My local box is running Windows 7, with Java 7.03 as well. I don't want to make too many assumptions, but I think it's reasonable to assume that Server 2008 and Windows 7 are pretty similar. (The OS architecture is the same.) Aside from that, my local box has identical hardware to our servers.

Comment: Might help if you provided the OS the application/server is running so we can advise on commands or tools to use to monitor the underlying OS.

Comment: Q: What is the OS?  Q: Have you already tried monitoring at the OS level (e.g. Task Mgr and/or PerfMon for Windows, ps -eaf, top, iostat for Linux, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on the OS, I made the edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, you need to:

1) Establish a "performance baseline"

2) Try to reproduce the bottleneck, and compare the behavior under stress with the baseline

3) Identify the cause of the bottleneck, and correct it.

These links will help:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781394%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463394.aspx

You should also look at these TCP/IP registry settings:

- Increase the range of ephemeral ports

  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, MaxUserPort
- Consider disabling auto-tuning:

  http://geekswithblogs.net/cajunmcse/archive/2010/08/20/windows-2008-exchange-and-tcpip-auto-tuning.aspx